# How can i take a part of a text on a link? Selenium and Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

im new with Selenium and Python. I want to extract the IMDB Film ID from his link, for example: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6423886/

I just need this: tt6423886

The problem is that i can get that link with selenium find element link, but then i dont know how to take only tt6423886.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome ('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get ('cinecalidad.to/espana/')
pelicula_1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(3) div:nth-child(1) > div.home_post_cont.post_box:nth-child(1)')
pelicula_1.click()
numid = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.single_left:nth-child(5) tbody:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(3)')
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: One simple way is to take the link string and split it: `link_string.split('/')[-2]` and then the [-2] gets the 2nd-to-last part of the phrase

Comment: im using pycharm and it says me that link_string it's a unresolved reference. this is my code''from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome ('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get ('http://www.cinecalidad.to/espana/')
pelicula_1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(3) div:nth-child(1) > div.home_post_cont.post_box:nth-child(1)')
pelicula_1.click()
numid = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.single_left:nth-child(5) tbody:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(3)')'

Comment: The reason for that error is that selenium wants the url to start with 'http' or 'https' in the driver.get() statement.

Comment: the http it's putted but idont know why it doesnt copied

Comment: i have this page [link](http://www.cinecalidad.to/espana/pelicula/happy-anniversary-2018-online-descarga/), and where puts IMDB is my link with the code that i want, how can i take only the code for copy it and then paste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the *IMDB Film ID* from the link `https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6423886/` you can use *Python's* [**`split()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) method as follows :

- Code Block :

  ```
  print("Page URL is : %s" %driver.current_url)
  url = driver.current_url
  url_parts = url.split("/")
  print("The part I wanted was : %s" %url_parts[4])
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output :

  ```
  Page URL is : https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6423886/
  The part I wanted was : tt6423886
  ```

Comment: This is not working. My starting page must be cinecalidad.to/espana/, from there i scrap the imdb link, and then need to take the id. The problem it's when call current_url it takes https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6423886/ for you because you started there, for me it's taking cinecalidad.to/espana/.

Comment: @DanielMirandaMari Whenever you reach the IMDb page use the code block to retrieve your results.

Comment: when i reach IMDb page and ask for current url still telling me my page url is http://www.cinecalidad.to/espana/pelicula/happy-anniversary-2018-online-descarga/ . Maybe because the link it's opening in a new tab¿ If that's why, how can i open the link in same tab?

Comment: @DanielMirandaMari This is a separate issue. For debugging you can put a hard wait for the url to get changed to `https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6423886/` and raise a new question with your new requirement. SO volunteers will be happy to help you out.